# Effects on performance when choosing object over timeStamp

Tags: mongodb, database

I'm working on a chat application and currently working on designing the DB (mongoDB). I have a `message` schema that has the following structure:

```
{
  from : id,
  to : id,
  content : String,
  createdAt : timeStamp
}
```

while the above schema is fairly simple, I was wondering if I can update `createdAt` to something like the following:

```
createdAt : {
    year : YYYY, 
    month : MM,
    date : DD,
    hour : HH,
    minute : MM,
    seconds : SS
}
```

while the above sounds too much, this can help me avoid headache of converting back the timeStamp to a user-friendly date when showing it to the end user. I can show time like `createdAt.hour + ' ' + createdAt.minute` instead of doing `new Date(timeStamp)` all the time.

I have the following doubts:

1. Is storing object VS timeStamp will cause any performance impacts when making DB queries. (considering that both of them are indexed)
2. What's the most appropriate way of storing time for an entity if not timeStamp. (As I've read on a few blogs storing Date object slows down the query too much)

PS. This is my first time designing the whole system by myself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it may cause performance impacts, because you will be using compound index, so that your query use index scan rather then record scan, and when you create single index on time stamp range queries become simple and will use index.